# Linux kernel re-compilation too slow

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

I am compiling the Linux kernel in a VM(virtual box) with 2 out of 4GB and 4 out of 8 CPUs allocated. My initial compilation took around 8-9 hours, and I was using make -j4 optimisation too. Now I added a simple system call to the kernel and just ran the make -j4 and and it has been compiling for the past 3 hours. I thought that after the initial compilation, make would only compile the small changes but it seems to be compiling everything (mostly the drivers). Is there any way I can speed up this compilation process?

For example, is there anyway by which I can disable some of the drivers that I don't really need, for example if I just want to implement a simple system call, I don't really need all the networking drivers, and maybe that would speed it up? i.e. I just want the bare minimum functionality for my kernel to test my system calls.

Comment: You should give more memory and CPU to your VM, or else build natively rather than in a virtual machine.  Also check how you've configured your virtual disk.  As for why everything is rebuilding, it depends on what files you changed.  If you changed a common file that all or most of the drivers include, then make will rebuild them all.  So, it depends on what parts of the code you touched when you added your simple system call.

Comment: @MadScientist, it was the hello world system call , I modified the syscalls.h file for it. I think that is used as a header in all drivers, so that could be the reason. I have a max limit of 4gb ram, and my host os is Windows, so I really can't go beyond that.

Comment: You can definitely disable all the drivers and use a minimal config. You should also check if you're swapping. `-j4` may be too many processes for your available RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the kernel will always take a very long time, unfortunately there's no way around that besides having a really good processor with a lot of multi threading, however in huge projects like this, [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) will help with compilation times tremendously, it's not perfect, but far better than just compiling objects.

You won't see the difference at the initial compilation, but it will speed up recompilation by using the cache it has generated instead of compiling most of what already has been compiled before.